# Puppet agent not requesting cert

Tags: puppet, certificate

Trying to setup Puppet agent/master on a single machine (planning to install more agents once this is working). I'm mired down in the cert signing process right now, which feels like it should be easy..

Start the server by hand, it creates a ca cert

```
$ sudo puppet master --no-daemonize --verbose
Info: Creating a new SSL key for ca
Info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for ca
Info: Certificate Request fingerprint (SHA256): 59:31:5B:35:9B:45:4B:36:7F:08:3A:80:2E:4C:78:2F:95:6B:33:45:E4:46:54:E8:8F:33:E8:62:15:1D:A8:DE
Notice: Signed certificate request for ca
Notice: Rebuilding inventory file
Info: Creating a new certificate revocation list
Info: Creating a new SSL key for box.localdomain
Info: Creating a new SSL certificate request for box.localdomain
Info: Certificate Request fingerprint (SHA256): D3:88:48:BD:D6:64:EE:9B:3A:C1:06:C6:9D:4E:74:06:B3:09:BA:82:D1:91:0E:1A:DA:7D:55:0B:7B:83:C6:3F
Notice: box.localdomain has a waiting certificate request
Notice: Signed certificate request for box.localdomain
Notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::CertificateRequest box.localdomain at '/etc/puppet/ssl/ca/requests/box.localdomain.pem'
Notice: Removing file Puppet::SSL::CertificateRequest box.localdomain at '/etc/puppet/ssl/certificate_requests/box.localdomain.pem'
Notice: Starting Puppet master version 3.3.0-rc2
```

Start the client by hand, expecting it to create a cert request:

```
$ sudo puppet agent --test --waitforcert 60 
[sudo] password for mystro: 
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Caching catalog for box.localdomain
Info: Applying configuration version '1378835927'
Notice: Finished catalog run in 0.04 seconds
```

Look for cert requests (no output)

```
$ sudo puppet cert list
```

Why wouldn't the agent be requesting a cert to be signed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cert is already signed.

You need to add the --all flag to your puppet invocation to see the certs that are already signed.  You can run `puppet <command> --help` for more information on running puppet commands.

Comment: Ah, I presume it's already signed since the master and agent are on the same box. Thanks for your answer!